# Getting added child from firebase database, It freezes UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing a simple Chat view controller. While getting added child from firebase, It freezes UI until it gives the last child. Strange behavior. 
Here is the code snippet-

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    chatArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    ref=(FIRDatabaseReference *)[[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    refHandleForGettingChatInfo=[[ref child:@"Chat"]  observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
     {
     NSLog(@"New chat");
     NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *message = snapshot.value;
     [chatArray addObject:message];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [tblChat reloadData];
     });
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table View delegates and DataSources
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return chatArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier =@"ChatTableViewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
     {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    NSDictionary *message=[chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=[message valueForKey:@"userName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[message valueForKey:@"userMessage"];

    return cell;
}
```

Xcode version: 8.3.2

Deployment target: 10.2

If anyone has faced the same issue please let me know what is the most suitable solution for this scenario. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**updated answer:**

```
 NSOperationQueue *dataQue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
            [dataQue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    chatArray=[NSMutableArray new];
ref=(FIRDatabaseReference *)[[FIRDatabase database] reference];
refHandleForGettingChatInfo=[[ref child:@"Chat"]  observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
 {
 NSLog(@"New chat");
 NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *message = snapshot.value;
 [chatArray addObject:message];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [tblChat reloadData];
 });
 });
}];
                }];
            }];
```

Comment: I have replaced my listener code with your code, still it hangs.

Comment: I updated call ur ** reloadata**. in dispatch_get_main_queue I think it will resolve ur issues

Comment: Okay let me check NAVEEN

Comment: Nothing improved Naveen, dispatch_get_main_queue() is a good idea. Reload tableview in main thread but firebase block is too fast to handle over main thread. I have 15 records in firebase database, It hangs UI until It gives me the 15th record.